# ag grid : js : How to find which filter is applied

Tags: ag-grid

I have data displayed in ag grid.
It has 4 columns name,age,sport and has the following data:-

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3B3y6.png)

now when I filter the data based on "sport" , lets say uncheck "blanks"
I get the following data:- 
 [filtered data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0X9Fo.png)

1)My questions is how to get the which filter is applied on columns ,
like in this case "blanks" is applied on "sport".

2)If I refresh the data using 
api.setRowdata(), filter applied to the columns are lost

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1.how to get the which filter is applied on columns

You can get it using `gridApi.filterManager.allFilters`

Check this live example [ag-grid: Built-In Filters - log the filters applied](https://plnkr.co/edit/sIBBYvp57Bn7oEdfQHzM?p=preview).

Apply `age` and `year` filters and then click `Log Filter` button.

> age: {column: Column, filterPromise: Promise, scope: null, compiledElement: null, guiPromise: {…}}
>   year: {column: Column, filterPromise: Promise, scope: null, compiledElement: null, guiPromise: {…}}
>   __proto__: Object

Answer (score 7):

Starting from `ag-grid@19.0.0` to **get** or **set** all applied filters you can take advantage of using:

```
const savedModel = gridApi.getFilterModel();
gridApi.setFilterModel(savedModel);
```

Answer (score 1):

For the

> 2. if I refresh the data using `api.setRowdata()`, filter applied to the columns are lost

we can use the following settings for columns in `columnDefs` object :-

```
filterParams: {
    newRowsAction: 'keep'
}
```