# How to get a notification of column name/filter type when a filter is applied to a ag grid column

Tags: angular, filter, ag-grid

I am trying to get a notification when i change a filter/ apply a filter on a ag grid. Below is the code that i tried.

In my component.html i have added `(filterChanged) = 'filterChanged($event)' .`

In component.ts my code is as below,

```
filterChanged(params){
this.params =params; 
this.gridApi = params.api; // To access the grids API
this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;
var filterInstance = this.gridApi.filterManager.allFilters;
alert("Filter applied"+filterInstance);
}
```

But here in alert i am getting as Object Object, no idea why so. Can anyone please help on this.

I referred to the below link -

[[ag grid : js : How to find which filter is applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51039682/ag-grid-js-how-to-find-which-filter-is-applied][1])

Answer (score 1):

`filterInstance` is an object and when you use

```js
alert("Filter applied"+filterInstance);
```

Javascript implicitly converts it a string using `filterInstance.toString()` in order to display it in the browser. Any object `toString()` will give you `[object Object]`, which isn't very useful. If you want to see the data in JSON format, you can use:

```js
alert("Filter applied" + JSON.stringify(filterInstance));
```

Comment: Yeah now i am able get the json as expected, but i am getting only the first filtered string. If select one filter it's not giving that. Is there any other way to get all the filters applied.?

Comment: @AkshayKrishna What version of `ag-grid` are you using?

Comment: ag grid version is : v18.1.2